# A canonical map Aut$_{\mathsf{Lie}_R}(\mathfrak{n} \rtimes_\pi \mathfrak{g}) \to$ Aut$_{\mathsf{Lie}_R}(\mathfrak{n})$

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-algebras

Let $\mathfrak{n}$, $\mathfrak{g} \in \mathsf{Lie}_R$ be two Lie algebras over a commutative ring $R$, s.t. $\mathfrak{g}$ acts on $\mathfrak{n}$ as a derivation: $\pi:\mathfrak{g} \to \text{Der}(\mathfrak{n})$.
Is there a "canonical" map Aut$_{\mathsf{Lie}_R}(\mathfrak{n} \rtimes_\pi \mathfrak{g}) \to$ Aut$_{\mathsf{Lie}_R}(\mathfrak{n})$? Simple Pre- and postcomposition with inclusion and projection does not work, but maybe one could use the fact, that $\mathfrak{n}$ is a $\mathfrak{n} \rtimes_\pi \mathfrak{g}$-module. If not, is there at least one on the level of derivations?

Comment: There is no such canonical map in the following case: let $\mathfrak{a}_k(R)=R^k$ be endowed with the standard action of $\mathfrak{sl}_k$. Then there is no such canonical map when $\mathfrak{h}=\mathfrak{n}\rtimes\mathfrak{g}$ is $(\mathfrak{a}_k\oplus\mathfrak{a}_k)\rtimes\mathfrak{sl}_k$ and $\mathfrak{n}=\mathfrak{a}_k\oplus\{0\}$, because the ideal $\mathfrak{n}$ is not invariant under the automorphism group (say for $k=2$ and $R$ any field of characteristic 0).

Comment: In this example $\mathfrak{n}$ is also not stable by self-derivations of $\mathfrak{h}$, e.g. by the derivation $(v,v',s)\mapsto (0,v,0)$.

Comment: Well, you could always take the map that is constant with value the identity.  This is a "canonical" map between any two groups.  But I don't think it's what you're looking for.